# DNS and MX questions related to new hosts

Tags: dns, mx

This stuff always confuses me so I'll layout the pieces and what I hope to achieve, if someone can connect the dots.

- I have a domain `www.toys.com`
- I have a cloud VPS
- I have an Open Exchange mail server

In a perfect world...get `toys.com` to point to and use cloud VPS's DNS settings. This is great my domain now has a web host, hooray.

I don't want to use cloud VPS mail services. I want to use Open Exchange services. So I go into cloud VPS's DNS tools and add records for open exchange service and mail should work, hooray.

My problem as follows `toys.com` currently has existing hosting and a separate mail server.

- When I switch the DNS of `toys.com` to point to new web host, I know existing hosting will stop.
- When I switch the DNS of `toys.com` to point to new web host, I think mail will also stop because the records are no longer there since there's a new host.
- I now have to add the Open Exchange mail server records in cloud VPS's DNS tools. How long will this take?

The reason I ask is because the mail server is hosting about 400 email addresses, but a new web host is wanted/needed.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I do move my domain and DNS, I would setup the new DNS before. Then when you update your existing DNS to point to new DNS, you only have to wait for the propagation which could take around 12hrs depending on how far the DNS is away (meaning sometimes countries differ a bit on time as there is a few DNS hops between them)

Comment: DNS propagation can sometimes take up to 72 hours...it's advisable to leave the previous hosting up for at least that period of time (if not longer to collect missing data if need be).